# Powershell login to winServer2019's mySQL 8 Error 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake

Tags: windows-10, powershell, mysql, windows-server-2019

Getting the following error when trying to login to mysql use mysql.exe or mysqldump.exe

```
mysql: Unknown OS character set 'cp0'.
mysql: Switching to the default character set 'utf8mb4'.
ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake
```

- Server is running 3x instances of sql 8x, 5x, xx
- Installed PHP7 && mysql 8 for wordpress site
- this is not an issue w/ running due to calling the .exe directly from dir

Tried the following:

1. [This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144451/mysql-server-version-5-7-but-if-i-want-to-access-from-console-i-am-happy-to-help?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. added character-set-server = utf8 to my.ini

Pretty much running low on options.